# Does tail risk disappear in the long horizon in any rolling over strategy with shorter frequency?

Tags: risk, risk-management, yield

Say I am investing to gain weekly yields ${y_{i}}$ for over a year, gaining the overall yield:

$\prod_{n=1}^{52} (1+y_i) -1$

The most dominant term in the above product is the sum of all yields, which by CLT should now converge to a normal distribution even if short horizon returns are themselves 'fat tailed'. (Assuming yields are iid).

These yields could correspond to successively selling an OTM covered calls (with strikes adjusted so that the theoretical probability of call is approximately constant), which is extremely fat tailed in the short term, but if I look at the yearly yield, it is almost normal and very well behaved.

Comment: The convergence holds if the returns are sufficiently iid - but yes, mathematically speaking. The option strategy,though, will be problematic in the short term also as you will have to incur margin calls, effectively busting your account on every tail event.

Comment: Note that application of CLT requires finite variance of short terms returns, which a few people (including some here, and the famous mathematician Mandelbrot) deny is the case.